# Session expired during the ajax request in php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem that the session was expired and then I have clicked on a button which makes the ajax request, then on it holds & do nothing, in the console it displays as an error, if it is any other action then it redirects to login page but for the ajax it does nothing. Now what I need is that even on the ajax request it should get redirect to login page if the session gets expired. The main thing is that I have plenty of ajax calls in my application and I need to make a common script for all the ajax requests to get redirect to login page.
    Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

1. Call the server side file through ajax
2. Check for the session in the server side.
3. If session expired send response as session expired.
4. In the ajax success call back check the session expired data always.
5. If you found session expired value redirect to login using location.href.
   Just a skeleton code below.

   ```
   $.post('URL',{},
   function (data) {
     if (data.sessionexpired) {
      location.href = 'login.php';
     } else {
     //Normal process
   }
   ```

   }
     
     );

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer, I have tried that before, the problem is for how many scripts I should wirte this? that is what I've mentioned in my question, as "The main thing is that I have plenty of ajax calls in my application...."

Comment: How you are using ajax in your application? like using Jquery ajax, post or get?

Answer (score 0):

have the ajax request return an error code or the string `error_go_home` or something.

if the javascript that recieves that message gets that string, have the javascript redirect them home.